# How to share files to another app using Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, file, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using the below code to share the files to other apps using xamarin iOS. but i didnt get any response. Is there any other option to share files to other apps using Xamarin iOS?
**Ref**: http://xamarinhelp.com/share-dialog-xamarin-forms/

```
public async Task Show(string title, string message, string filePath)
        {
            var items = new NSObject[] { NSObject.FromObject(title), NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath) };
            var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(items, null);
            var vc = GetVisibleViewController();

            NSString[] excludedActivityTypes = null;

            if (excludedActivityTypes != null && excludedActivityTypes.Length > 0)
                activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                if (activityController.PopoverPresentationController != null)
                {
                    activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = vc.View;
                }
            }
            await vc.PresentViewControllerAsync(activityController, true);
        }

        UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

            if (rootController.PresentedViewController == null)
                return rootController;

            if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                return ((UINavigationController)rootController.PresentedViewController).TopViewController;
            }

            if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                return ((UITabBarController)rootController.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
            }

            return rootController.PresentedViewController;
        }
```